# Trouble showing from first principles the equation describing the motion of a water drop through a cloud

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, atmospheric-science, rocket-science

If we had a water drop, initially of mass $m_0$ and speed $v_0$, falling through a cloud for a time
T and during this time its mass increases at a constant rate $\alpha m_0$, through accretion of
water vapour initially at rest.

How would we show from first principles that, neglecting air resistance, the equation describing
the motion of the water drop through the cloud is : $$d[(1 + αt)v]/dt = g(1 + αt)$$

I 'm trying to apply the technique we get from the rocket equation where we consider the change in momentum $\Delta P$, and consider the momentum before and after - but all I run into is $$ -m_0g \delta{t} = m_0(1+\alpha \delta{t})\delta{v} - \alpha \delta{t}v $$ which I seemingly can't manipulate any further.

Any pointers? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with the second law of dynamics:
$$ \frac{dp}{dt} = mg$$
We have to consider that here the mass is variable.
$$p(t) = m(t)v(t) = m_0(1 + \alpha t)v $$
Then:
$$ \frac{dm}{dt}v + \frac{dv}{dt}m = mg$$
Since the rate of change of the mass is $\frac{dm}{dt} = m_0\alpha$
$$ m_0 \alpha  v + m_0(1 + \alpha t)\frac{dv}{dt} = m_0(1 + \alpha t)v$$
Finally we have:
$$ \frac{d[(1 + \alpha t)v]}{dt} = (1 + \alpha t)g$$

Comment: Yeah thanks I see. This is much simpler as I was trying to go all the way from first principles.